# How to change the jtable data by clicking the search button?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, refresh, rowfilter

I have here a not so short working code. I need help in my search button. If I type in the `textfield` and click the search button the table data should be changed to what is written in the `textfield`. If it doesn't searched anything then the table should be blank.  What I can't make it work here is the showing of the new data into the table. Should I remove the first data and then `repaint()`? Or is there a better solution for that?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

public class TableSearch {

    JFrame Card = new JFrame();
    static JTable table;
    JTabbedPane card_tab = new JTabbedPane(); // FOR TAB
    JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel(); // FOR BUTTON BELOW
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
    Border etch = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white, Color.gray);
    Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
    JTextField text;

    public TableSearch() throws SQLException, IOException {
        Card.setVisible(true);
        Card.setSize(821, 421);
        Card.setTitle("File Maintenance");
        Card.setResizable(false);

        final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - Card.getWidth()) / 2);
        int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - Card.getHeight()) / 2);

        Card.setLocation(x, y);
        Card.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        container.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
        //container.setBorder(margin);

        JPanel labelpanel = new JPanel();
        labelpanel.setLayout(flow);
        labelpanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 0));

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Description:");
        label_1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 20));
        label_1.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        labelpanel.add(label_1);

        text = new JTextField();
        text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        labelpanel.add(text);

        JButton btnsearch = new JButton("Search");
        btnsearch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 20));
        btnsearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String search = text.getText();
                System.out.println(search);
                //What should I put here to change the table data???
            }
        });
        labelpanel.add(btnsearch);

        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
        jp1.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
        //jp1.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(etch,margin));
        jp1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        table = new JTable(new TableModel());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
        header.setBackground(new Color(224, 223, 227));
        header.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 20));
        table.setRowHeight(25);
        jp1.add(scrollPane);

        Card.add(container);
        container.add(labelpanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        container.add(jp1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static class TableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        public TableModel() {
            super(new Object[]{"Description", "Code", "Price"}, 0);
            for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
                addRow(new Object[]{index, index, index});
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Use the event dispatch thread for Swing components
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new TableSearch();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TableSearch.class.getName())
                          .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TableSearch.class.getName())
                          .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), in particular [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: @MadProgrammer ah no. I can already search in my original program. The only reason why I didn't include it in my code is because it came from database and it is in a hashmap. But my main problem is that I don't know how to put the item searched in the table.

Comment: Assuming you have the data, why not just use `addRow` of the `TableModel`...It accepts data in form of `Object[]`...`TableModel` is a really badly named class by the way, as there is already a `TableModel` in `javax.swing.Table` package ;)

Comment: ( because it came from database and it is in a hashmap v.s. and click the search button the table data should be changed to ) then this question is wrong asked, do you want to search in Databases or JTable, btw don't to use HasMap, use array based on util.List,

Comment: @MadProgrammer i'm sorry for the class name. I'll edit it right away. addRow is good but how can I add the row when my table model is in a method? I mean how will it be determined by the program that the search button is clicked and the data should be changed?

Comment: `TableModel model = (TableModel)JTable.getModel();`....

Comment: @mKorbel Well.. I don't think it's wrong because I have written `How to change the jtable data by clicking the search button?` By just clicking the search button. I never said that I needed to search in jtable or database because I already have done that. ` What I can't make it work here is the showing of the new data into the table.`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you but I figure it out now. I just replaced my whole table and change the data in my hashmap.

Comment: @user3771102 1. ??? but accepted this is your question, then result (wrong) is described in your last comment to MadProgrammer

Comment: @user3771102 you can use setDataVector(Object [][] rowData, Object [] colNames) method of DefaultTableModel class.

Comment: @mKorbel what result that is wrong? I only changed my default table model into abstract model so that I can clear easily the table data which is in the arraylist hashmap and then replace the hashmap with the hashmap of the searched data.

Answer (score 0):

@mKorbel Here is what I did that really works. I changed my `Table Model` to `AbstractModel`

```
public static class JTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = new String[] {"Description", "PLU Code", "Cash Price"};
    private static final Class<?>[] COLUMN_TYPES = new Class<?>[] {String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class};

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

     public int getRowCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {

        return COLUMN_NAMES[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return COLUMN_TYPES[columnIndex];
    }

     public Object getValueAt(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return products.get(rowIndex).get("proddesc");
            case 1: return products.get(rowIndex).get("prodcode");
            case 2: return products.get(rowIndex).get("price");

            default: return "Error";
        }
    }   

    public void removeRow(int row)
    {
        products.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }


}

private static class JTableButtonMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private final JTable table;

    public JTableButtonMouseListener(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int column = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
        int row    = e.getY()/table.getRowHeight(); 

        if (row < table.getRowCount() && row >= 0 && column < table.getColumnCount() && column >= 0) {
            Object value = table.getValueAt(row, column);
            if (value instanceof JButton) {
                ((JButton)value).doClick();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then this is what I did for my search button:

```
            JButton btnsearch = new JButton("Search");
            btnsearch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90,20));
            btnsearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    String search = text.getText();
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productSearch = all.posMain.getProductsSearch(search);

                    System.out.println(productsSearch);
                    products.clear();
                    table.repaint();
                    products = productSearch;

                }
            });
            labelpanel.add(btnsearch);
```

Since the everything is stored in the Hashmap I only changed my first hashmap to the 2nd hashmap by doing this: `products = productSearch;` after that everything worked fine.

Comment: 1. use array based on util.List, because HashMap hasn't internal index, you have an issue with indexing in JTables view (row sorter/filter, Renderer where is required convert index from view to model)

Comment: 2. ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productSearch = all.posMain.getProductsSearch(search); is wrong, again for why reson is there more that one array contains the same data, value structure

Comment: 3. table.repaint(); talking about JTable and its model isn't correctly setted, missed notifiers from model to view or used incorrectly (replace, refresh to model required notifier), underlaing array is wrong designed or incorect type of array, issue with EDT

Comment: 4. create an array (whatever array inc. HashWhatever), create JTable with DefaultTableModel, search in array (util.List is better designed for Comparator / Collator), filter array, reset DefaultTableModel, add filtered output from Comparator / Collator as new Vector of Vestor to the DefaultTableModel, no flashing, delaying, issue with graphical repainting, not required table.repaint();, only issue with EDT (only mouse hover_ove JTable can caused reoaintg with a new set of data)

Comment: 5. again wrong question, incorrectly described, with miss_interpering of description in the Oracle tutorial - How to use Tables, then wrong output in your answer aka kill_and_shut_up_to_@mKorbel